# Get rid of the Manufacturer (tag)

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tag-cleanup-request

[manufacturer](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/manufacturer) looks quite useless for the 7 questions it has... Let's just get rid of it! Too meta for us

Comment: Yup. Burn it up!

Comment: Done. Just VtD the posts.

Answer (score 1):

[manufacturer](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/manufacturer) has been removed from all questions where it was used.